# install specific component on a package (beginner)

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, vuejs2, npm-install

Im using [element UI](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/installation) and I'm installing it just like this

```
npm i element-ui -S
```

however i dont want the whole package instead i just want a specific component which is the [DatePicker](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/date-picker) how can I install it using npm. I tried looking in documentation but it is nowhere to be found thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using npm (or even Yarn), you can only install an entire package and all of it's dependencies. Installing specific parts of a package isn't a thing; more docs can be found [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install). Once again, even the docs for `element-ui` makes it quite clear that installing the package can only be done through

```
npm i element-ui -S
```

or if you're using yarn, `yarn install` 'ing after adding the package to your `package.json`.

Now, if you're wondering if it's possible to only include the component you want in the output bundle of your Vue app, then the answer is yes. You'll need to ensure that you're importing only the full path of the component (as opposed to the entire package):

```
import ElementUI from 'element-ui'; // will import the whole library
```

***OR***

```
import { DatePicker } from 'element-ui/lib/Datepicker' // will import only the Datepicker
```

You'll need to ensure that the path you're importing the component from matches that of the installed package location within your `node_modules` directory. As well, you'll then need to make sure that your Webpack config is setup correctly to bundle only the JS files you're importing (which should be handled by default).

Comment: can i ask a question sir? Does this import makes the app much more faster than importing the whole library?

Comment: A specific import will decrease the overall size of your app bundle. If you stick to this type of import, as opposed to importing the entire library of every dependency you have, then yes, you will experience a performance improvement.

Comment: i thought it was the same

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to only install one single component from a ui library.
Because there has a lot of dependency between each component in the source code.
But if you are worry about it's to heavy to import the whole library into your project.

Maybe the best way is import the library on demand like below:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { DatePicker } from 'element-ui'

Vue.use(DatePicker)
```

When using it with `webpack` and `babel-plugin-component`.
Your bundle output will only include code from the library which is actually useful.
You can see the detail document here [Element QuickStart](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/quickstart).(Ps: the **On demand** section)

Or you can discard to use ElementUI.
And choose another DatePicker Component for Vue from this site [Awesome Vue](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#calendar)

Comment: can i ask a question sir? Does this import makes the app much more faster than importing the whole library?

Comment: Same as Xenyal says, it's a good practice to import library on demand(if possible).